# MLE from a bivariate distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I have a sample of size $n$ from a bivariate distribution which have joint `pdf` with below form

$f_X(x)f_Y(y) \left[1+\lambda\left(2F_X(x)-1\right)\left(2F_Y(y)-1\right)\right]$

My goal is to estimate `MLE` for the parameter $\lambda$ where $-1 < \lambda < +1$

Overall I know how to construct the log-likelihood function to obtain `MLE`, however I stuck here as the value of $\lambda$ is restricted. So I wonder how can I design the optimisation rule to take care of such constraint

There is a similar discussion available in [Constrained Maximum Lilkihood Estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44133/constrained-maximum-lilkihood-estimation)

However I could not understand below discussion

[image]

I also looked into the theory of `Karush-Kuhn-Tucker`, but could not relate this to above discussion. Why we should have $\frac {\partial\Lambda}{\partial \lambda} \leq 0$? Shouldn't it be $\frac {\partial\Lambda}{\partial \lambda} = 0$ because we are looking for maximisation? Appreciate if you can help understanding above discussion from that post.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by an "optimisation rule"?  Certainly there's no conceptual problem with limiting $\lambda:$ you merely have to explore solutions within the interval $(-1,1).$

Comment: By optimisation rule, I meant to say that if/how I need to make any specific attention to find the maximum value of `log-likelihood` function due to the presence of this constraint

Comment: If it is a constraint optimization problem, then just use constraint optumization tools.

Comment: The photo is an explanation and analysis of the KKT conditions.  The "multipliers" to which it refers are the $x_i,$ which appear to be the Lagrange multipliers for the boundary conditions $\lambda - 1 = 0$ and $\lambda + 1 = 0.$

Comment: But why $\frac {\partial\Lambda}{\partial \lambda} \leq 0$?

Comment: Have you considered replacing $\lambda$ with a [hyperbolic tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/980503) transformation?